# Cucumber-js Loop within the StepDef file

Tags: selenium, cucumberjs

Is there a way, from the Step Def File, to loop over the same Then method?
I have a scenario where my I need to do the same thing over and over again, which I have currently implemented in a single Then method. However that is failing with the following: 
`Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 30000 milliseconds`.
I know I could increase the timeout, I would rather not.

The problem is the thing I want to do has a varied output, so the number of times I need iterate over the While varies from run to run. 
Is there a way to do something like this?

```
Scenario:
When I do a thing
Then I do another thing
While <some condition>
    Then I do this thing
Then Verify info is correct
```

Answer (score 0):

Are using Scenario Outlines an option? They will run the scenario multiple times not just the step https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline

Comment: It really wont work, the issue is, the number of Steps to get to the end of the scenario changes each time. The idea is it is a quiz, where each question has point assigned to it, there are 100+ questions in the quiz, each having its own point value. A user has to reach a certain number of points before they complete a quiz. So sometimes it could be 5 questions, other times it could take 10.

Comment: Do you need to do the loop in gherkin? Why not do the while loop in the .js step?  

You could pass in a JSON with data to populate in the loop.